# Android app hangs with a white screen for 12 seconds

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the program I needed to write:

1. Declare numerator and denominator variables
2. Start a loop:
   a) Wait for 3000 milliseconds
   b) Replace the text in the TextView (id: division_TextView) with the result of this: numerator / denominator
   c) Reduce denominator by 1

And this is what I got:

```
package com.example.debugging

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        division()
    }

    private fun division() {
        val numerator = 60
        val denominator = 4
        repeat(4) {
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            Log.d(TAG, "Text ${findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_TextView).text} was replaced by ${numerator / denominator}")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_TextView).text = "${numerator / denominator}"
            denominator--
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem: after starting the application, it hangs with a blank white screen. And only after about 12 seconds it shows the number 60 (i.e. it just ran the last time and replaced the text with 60).

"There is a logical explanation for this, because I run devision() from onCreate i.e. even before my application was visible to the user" I thought and put devision in onResume (i.e. I wanted the loop with Thread.sleep to start executing after the application became visible to the user). This is what my code looked like after these edits:

```
package com.example.debugging

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        division()
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume started.")
    }

    private fun division() {
        val numerator = 60
        var denominator = 4
        repeat(4) {
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            Log.d(TAG, "Text ${findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_TextView).text} was replaced by ${numerator / denominator}")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_TextView).text = "${numerator / denominator}"
            denominator--
        }
    }
}
```

However, the situation has not changed at all, everything is the same.

Below I added screenshots of the application launch and the startup log (of my second code).

```
D/MainActivity: Text Hello World! was replaced by 15
W/MIUIScout App: Enter APP_SCOUT_WARNING State
W/MIUIScout App: Event:APP_SCOUT_WARNING Thread:main backtrace:
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:356)
        at com.example.debugging.MainActivity.division(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at com.example.debugging.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1476)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4952)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2318)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8298)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
I/ample.debuggin: Thread[6,tid=27409,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb40000789d63d000,peer=0x12cc19b8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/ample.debuggin: 
I/ample.debuggin: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
D/MainActivity: Text 15 was replaced by 20
W/MIUIScout App: Enter APP_SCOUT_HANG state
W/MIUIScout App: Event:APP_SCOUT_HANG Thread:main backtrace:
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:356)
        at com.example.debugging.MainActivity.division(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at com.example.debugging.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1476)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4952)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2318)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8298)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
I/ample.debuggin: Thread[6,tid=27409,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb40000789d63d000,peer=0x12cc19b8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/ample.debuggin: 
I/ample.debuggin: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
D/MainActivity: Text 20 was replaced by 30
D/MainActivity: Text 30 was replaced by 60
I/MainActivity: onResume started.
W/Activity: PerfMonitor: Slow Operation: Activity com.example.debugging/.MainActivity onResume took 12005ms
I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@a9c3d69
I/MsyncFactory: [static] sMsyncFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.MsyncFactoryImpl@77253ee
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true, sRendererEnabled = true, forceHwAccelerated = false
D/libMEOW: meow new tls: 0xb4000078335a07c0
D/libMEOW: applied 1 plugins for [com.example.debugging]:
D/libMEOW:   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
I/ample.debuggin: Thread[6,tid=27409,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb40000789d63d000,peer=0x12cc19b8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/ample.debuggin: 
W/Looper: PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=4 plan=19:07:58.191 late=202ms wall=12318ms running=0ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159 procState=-1
W/Looper: PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=com.example.debugging/.MainActivity time=1ms latency=12533ms running=0ms  procState=-1  historyMsgCount=4 (msgIndex=1 wall=57ms seq=1 late=10ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=162) (msgIndex=3 wall=144ms seq=3 late=60ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110) (msgIndex=4 wall=12318ms seq=4 late=202ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
I/ample.debuggin: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
```

[first 12 sec of an app launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iUPN.jpg)
[after 12 seconds have passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxxHr.jpg)

Comment: `Thread.sleep()`, if you don’t use it on a background thread, means, completely freeze my app for this amount of time and risk having it crash with the Application Not Responding error. Read up about how to use `runOnUiThread()` instead.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's that damn (official) codelab example again

Comment: @cactustictacs That's not the only codelab with egregious code in it, but maybe it's the worst.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's just amazing that it not only tells you to do the ultimate no-no, you're meant to be recording a video while preventing the display from updating! It's like a prank tutorial or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just gonna link to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73094604/13598222) I posted about this, which links to *other* answers because this comes up way too often. It's not you, the code on the official tutorial you're following is completely broken, and they're teaching you to so something you *fundamentally should not do* (and which means the example **does not work**).

If you have any questions though feel free!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I already thought I was doing something completely wrong... And sorry for asking the same question again, I guess I still need to learn how to use google :)

Comment: @IuriiMg oh hey don't worry about it, it's not your fault at all! You're following an official tutorial, doing exactly what they tell you to do, and it doesn't work. I just wish they'd fix it, it pops up regularly enough on here that it's obviously causing learners problems

Answer (score 0):

as i learned thread.sleep is not a good option for this kind of operations, that s why you are not able to see the result at every step. Could you try it with runnables. I wrote a sample for you, i have a start button and a textView to see the result.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


var runnable : Runnable = Runnable {  }
var handler : Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}


fun start(view: View) {

    val numerator = 60
    var denominator = 4

    runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            println("${numerator/denominator}")
            textView.text=(numerator/denominator).toString()
            handler.postDelayed(this,3000)
            denominator--
        }

    }

    handler.post(runnable)

    button.isEnabled = false


}
```

}

Comment: When you learn more about kotlin, you can use coroutines to not lock the main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will definitely try to solve this problem the way you described :)